# revert multiple (multiple columns to one column )

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset with answers from a survey of 17 questions (10 questions are 5 or 7 questions are 7 point scale), and now the data format gives me 5 or 7 columns for each question answer (True or False), which is like a one-hot encoding style. And I want to convert these columns back to 15 single column.

To be more specific, the data I have looks like the following

```
        Q1.1  Q1.2  Q1.3 Q1.4 Q1.5 Q1.6 Q1.7 .... Q17.1 Q17.2 ... Q17.5 
row1     T     F      F    F    F    F    F         F     T          F
  ...               ...
row2000  F     T      F    F    F    F    F         T     F          F
```

the desired format I want to have is

```
        Q1  Q2 .... Q17
row1    1    4       2  # with number indicating the value that the column is True
           ....
row2000 2    3       1  #(e.g., if Q2.4 is T, then for Q2, it is 4).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R approach using `split.default` and `max.col`. Using `split.default` we can split the columns based on the pattern in their name, so that every question is divided into a list. Assuming every question would have only one `TRUE` value we can use `max.col` to find the `TRUE` index.

```
sapply(split.default(df, sub("\\..*", "", names(df))), max.col)

#     Q1 Q2
#[1,]  1  2
#[2,]  6  5
```

**data**

```
df <-read.table(text = "Q1.1 Q1.2 Q1.3 Q1.4 Q1.5 Q1.6 Q1.7 Q2.1 Q2.2  Q2.3 Q2.4 Q2.5
T     F      F    F    F    F    F         F     T          F F F
F     F      F    F    F    T    F         F     F          F F T", header = T)
```

This is assuming class of your data is "logical". If "T"/"F" is stored in character format (like in @Maurits answer) we need to convert them to logical first.

Using data from @Maurits Evers

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.logical)
sapply(split.default(df, sub("\\..*", "", names(df))), max.col)

#     Q1 Q17
#[1,]  1   2
#[2,]  2   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` option:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    rownames_to_column("row") %>%
    gather(k, v, -row) %>%
    separate(k, c("question", "part"), sep = "\\.") %>%
    filter(v == "T") %>%
    group_by(row) %>%
    select(-v) %>%
    spread(question, part)
## A tibble: 2 x 3
## Groups:   row [2]
#  row     Q1    Q17
#  <chr>   <chr> <chr>
#1 row1    1     2
#2 row2000 2     1
```

I assume that your original data contains `"T"`/`"F"` as `character` entries. If they are in fact `TRUE`/`FALSE`, you should change `filter(v == "T")` to `filter(v == TRUE)`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Q1.1  Q1.2  Q1.3 Q1.4 Q1.5 Q1.6 Q1.7  Q17.1 Q17.2  Q17.5
row1     T     F      F    F    F    F    F         F     T          F
row2000  F     T      F    F    F    F    F         T     F          F", colClasses = "character")
```